# Changing my default bittorrent?

Tags: kubuntu, bittorrent, transmission, deluge, ktorrent

My deluge would not launch.

I uninstalled it thinking that another one of my programs, i.e. . transmission, ktorrent would start opening my magnet links. I did not change my default program for opening these files, basically because I did not know how to.

Can someone please assist me in doing so?

Please, I am very new to ubuntu and my friend who had installed the system on my computer is actually in prison.. so i have no hopes of him guiding me through these issues. I am very lost.

Comment: On which web browser are you trying to download magnetic links? Or by any chance, are you just trying to open `.torrent` or similar file which pops up nothing?? Could you please clarify?

Comment: I feel sorry...

Answer (score 0):

To make a program your default; right click any .torrent file on your computer, "properties", go to "open with" tab. Choose the program you like and set it as default.

This would set the default program to open .torrent files, but it would not change the program that opens magnet links (sadly).

Setting the program that opens magnet links is a little bit harder. Try to follow [this](http://myinterestingubuntu.blogspot.com.es/2012/01/change-magnet-links-association-in.html) or try following me:

Firstly we need to check that your program's ".desktop file" (in `/usr/share/applications`) has this line:

```
MimeType=application/x-bittorrent;application/x-torrent;
```

To check, open the text editor (called gedit) and hit "open" up to the left, then navigate to your program's .desktop file. As stated; you should find it in the folder `/usr/share/applications`. After you open it, search for "MimeType" (by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> and typing "MimeType" in the box that shows up).

...If you did find that it has this line then proceed. (if not then just put the line in. Modify the existing line.) Close gedit.

---

Now that we've done the checking; open the file `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list` (the same way you opened the .desktop file). Search for "x-scheme-handler/magnet" (same way also). If you found it, make it look like this;

```
x-scheme-handler/magnet=YOURPROGRAM.desktop;
```

Replace YOURPROGRAM by the program you want to set default. The name must exactly match the name of your program's .desktop file.

example: `x-scheme-handler/magnet=kde4-ktorrent.desktop;`